# statistics - find confidence interval from a given estimator

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, confidence-interval, parameter-estimation

So I've been trying to solve this question:
we have $x_i$~$N(\mu,4)$.

an estimator $ T_1 = \frac{2x_1 +x_2}{3}$

we need to find confidence interval with $\alpha $ confidence level that is based on $T_!$ .

given hint:this needs to satisfy $P( \vert \frac{T_1 - \mu}{v} \vert<k)=1-\alpha $ . you need to find v and k.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: In notation $N(\mu,4),$ is 4 variance or standard deviation?

Comment: it is the variance

Comment: OK then. One step at a time: $T_1$ has a normal distribution. Its mean is $\mu.$ What is its variance? Next, can you get the answer for a 95% CI? And, finally, generalize.